# What version of Tridion was broker page storage introduced?

Tags: broker, cwa

I'm arguing with my colleague about which version of SDL Tridion introduced the ability to publish pages to the broker database?

I say 2011, he says 2009.

Are either of us right?

I was under the assumption that this functionality was built to support the CWA, if there's also more knowledge there I'd be interested to know.

Thanks

Comment: Are you still waiting for someone to provide another answer John? If not, you might want to accept an answer so that TSE's accept ratio increases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't like quoting myself, but... who are we kidding: I love quoting myself.

From [over on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690171/what-content-does-tridion-content-delivery-fetch-from-its-database):

> Tridion 5.3 was the first version where you got the option to store pages and binaries into the database. But the only way to retrieve them would then be through the API; so there wasn't a web site integration layer yet (unless you were already using the CWA).

Since you're asking when "publish pages to the broker database" was introduced, that would be version 5.3.

Answer (score 5):

The ability to store pages in the Broker database was introduced in Tridion 2009. CWA was already something developed way before that, as it was already working on Tridion 5.2

**Update**

See Frank's answer. Apparently it was already possible in 5.3..

Comment: He he... good old times. That logic was in the Tridion Delivery Framework project... tdf.jar :) I remember it he he

Comment: It might have been there too Mihai, but that was a PS module at the time. Since Tridion 2009 (I have a feeling it was earlier, but will take Raimon's word for it) there is also a Page storage module in one of the Content Delivery jars. It may have looked similar to the one from TDF, but it was a new implementation.

Comment: I thought it was earlier too, but then I checked broker configs and the DB scripts and indeed it was not there in 5.3.. Page Meta was already always in the broker I believe, maybe that's the confusion.

Comment: My feeling is based on who wrote the original page storage; that person wasn't at SDL anymore in 2009. I think Tridion 2009 might have added the classes/filters necessary to retrieve the pages. Those were missing for a while. :-)

Comment: John, Looks like your colleague was right. People should listen to him more often ;-)

Comment: It looks like you both were wrong, but I decided to write it up in an answer. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I had stored pages in Broker 5.3 SP1, SQLPageHome class inserts in Page_content table.
i got following from manual.

```
only if you intend to use the SDL Tridion Content Web Application
(CWA) Layer, add the following Binding elements:
• For Microsoft SQL Server:

<Binding Name="Page" Class="com.tridion.broker.pages.SQLPageHome" />
```